# Ajax cut 0 from float values

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have problem with disappearing 0 from my float numbers.

my sql query returns data like:

```
{'a': 99.99, 'c': 669.0, 'b': 99.0, 'e': 0.0, 'd': 9.0, 'g': 0.0, 'f': 0.0, 'f2': 0.0}
```

but when I am getting it in $.ajax response, there is no 0 after dot.

[image]

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/_edit_wishbone',
    data: editing_data,
    success: function(response) {
        $.each( response.row, function( key, value ) {
            $('.editing').children('.' + key).html( value);
        });

        $('.editing').removeClass('editing');
    }
});
```

Comment: can you do `console.log(response)`?what does it show?

Comment: _“I have problem with disappearing 0 from my float numbers”_ – first and foremost, you have a problem with understanding what _numbers_ are. Numbers don’t including any “formatting.”

Comment: Ok, I am trying explain as simple as my english skills allows me. Result is that I want to have .0 but I have not, so I described it as disappearing 0. Thank you for explain, in future I'll try to be more attentive  in the description of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use value.toFixed(1)

All numbers in Javascript are float, if the number is full integer, when displaying by default the dot and all following 0s will be ignored. 9.0 is the same as 9, when you try to display it JavaScript assumes you mean 9.

Comment: Ok, it solved my problem. Thank you for the explaining.